# BadgeValue not getting updated on UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I use `UITabBar` and `UITabBarItems` with it. I can set badge value for `UITabBarItem` before assigning `tabBarItem` to `tabBar`. But my problem is that I am not able to update the badge value of `tabBarItem`.

Here is code where I am able to set badge value initially:

```
// array of tabBarItems
NSMutableArray * tabs = [[NSMutableArray  alloc] init];

for(iterates few times)
{
    [tabs addObject:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:firstName image:nil tag:i]];
    // set tabItem's property
    [(UITabBarItem *)[tabs objectAtIndex:i] setFinishedSelectedImage:[self convertImage:iconImage toSize:CGSizeMake(iconWidth, TAB_ICON_HEIGHT)] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[self convertImage:iconImage toSize:CGSizeMake(iconWidth, TAB_ICON_HEIGHT)]];
    [[tabs objectAtIndex:0] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 2]];
}
// setting items of UITabBar
[self.chatTabBar setItems:tabs];
```

Here, I try to update the badge value. So what happens is that if I `NSLog` the new badge value it shows the updated value but I see no change in UI.

```
[[self.chatTabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1]];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it:

```
UIViewController *carrinhoVC = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

            carrinhoVC.tabBarItem.badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1];
```

carrinhoVC is the UIViewController that you want to update badge value inside TabBar.

Comment: 5 min ago you said that it worked, check it again, you are doing something really wrong, this code works very well.

Comment: I'll accept your answer if it comes to be my code fault. But be patience.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me:

```
if let tabBar = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
    let tabBarItem = tabBar.tabBar.items?[1] {
    tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil
}
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked by 'rockdaswift'